# Incorrect amount format to well format amount

Tags: php

I have a problem with amounts which I receive in a XML from suppliers. They format amount like: 1.235.50 instead of 1.235,50 or 1235.250
Is there a way to format it the right way?

Comment: wait. how is 1.235,50 a valid amount?

Comment: 1.235,50 is a Dutch amount notation

Comment: @KennethC, "." is for formatting IMO, but how is "1.235.50" a valid amount? Should it not be like "123.550" or "1235.50"?

Comment: Since after 1st period, you could replace commas to periods. Hence built in php magic like strpos and str_replace comes in handy! strpos to find first period, and str_replace to provide that magic the offset!

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
 echo number_format('1.235.50', 2, '.', '');
```

**EDIT:**
You can first remove all dots except that before the decimal part:

```
$count = substr_count($number, '.');
$number = str_replace('.', '', '1.235.50', $count-1);
```

and after that format the number if you want a different decimal part separator

```
 echo number_format($number, 2, ',', '');
```

*NOTE:* You can combine all of this in one line.

Comment: Nope, gives the exception: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Comment: Do the number you recieve always contains a decimal part (.00) at the end?

Comment: Yes it always contains a decimal part